# Evaluating the $\int \frac{x+2}{x^2-4x+8}$ - a doubt

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to find the antiderivative of $f(x) = \dfrac{x+2}{x^2-4x+8}$

I rewrote it to the form $$ \dfrac{x-2}{x^2 -4x + 8} + \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{4} (x-2)^2 +1}$$

The next step supposedly is $$F(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\ln|x^2-4x+8| + 2 \arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{2}(x-2)\right) + c$$

But now there is a problem which I've always had: I don't know why the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ in front of the $\ln(x)$ is there, same for the $2$ and the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ for the $\arctan(x)$. For me simplifying the function to standard integrals is easy, however finding the right factors and such is hard.

Comment: Differentiate $\ln|x^2-4x+8|$, and you'll discover why the $1/2$ is needed.

Comment: To know how to deal with the factors it is useful to bear in mind that $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(ax+b)=\frac{a}{(ax+b)^2+1}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(ax+b)=\frac{a}{ax+b}$.

Comment: In general, if you would like to integrate
$$
  \int\frac{dx}{\frac14(x-1)^2+1}
$$
you are going to use the formula for $\int \frac{dy}{1+y^2}$, so it is very natural to make a change of variables $y = \frac12(x-1)$

Comment: @DavidMitra The problem cuts both ways

Comment: Guess that the antiderivative is $\ln|x^2-4x+8|$. Now check. The derivative of our guess is $\color{maroon}{2x-4\over x^2-4x+8 }$.  Not the same as $x-2\over x^2-4x+8$. But things are easily rectified: ${x-2\over x^2-4x+8}={1\over 2}\color{maroon}{2x-4\over x^2-4x+8 }$. So the antiderivative is ${1\over 2}{\ln|x^2-4x+8|}$. (The "$u$-substitution method" formalizes this process.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas I didn't do that, the editor did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use substitution, we need to determine $u$ as a function of $x$, and so, as a sort of "reverse" chain rule, we need also two substitute $du$ as a function of $dx$:

$$\int \dfrac{x-2}{x^2 -4x + 8}\,dx$$

Here, $u = x^2 - 4x + 8 \implies \,du = 2x - 4 = 2(x-2)\,dx \iff \frac 12 du = x - 2 \,dx$

This gives our substituted integrand: 
$$\begin{align} \int \dfrac{x-2}{x^2 -4x + 8}\,dx & = \int \frac{\frac 12 \,du}{u} \\ \\ & = \frac 12 \int \frac {du}{u} \\ \\ & = \frac 12 \ln|u| + C =\frac 12 \ln|x^2 - 4x + 8| + C\tag{1}\end{align}$$

---

For the second term:

$$\int\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{4} (x-2)^2 +1}\,dx = \int \dfrac{1}{\left(\frac 12(x-2)\right)^2 + 1} \,dx$$

We let $$u = \frac 12(x - 2) \implies du = \frac 12 dx \implies 2 du = dx$$

Substituting we have $$\begin{align} \int\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac 12(x-2)\right)^2 + 1} \,dx & = \int \frac 1{u^2 + 1}\cdot(2\,du)  \\ \\ & = 2 \int \cdot \dfrac{1}{u^2 + 1} \,du \\ \\& = 2\arctan\left(u\right) + C \\ \\ & = 2 \arctan\left(\frac 12(x - 2)\right) + C \tag{2} \end{align}$$

---

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together:

$$F(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\ln|x^2-4x+8| + 2 \arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{2}(x-2)\right) + c$$

Comment: So if you substitute with $u$, you have to express everything as $u$?

Comment: And the $2$ in the second example comes from the fact that $1 = 2[\dfrac{1}{2}(x-2)]'$?

Comment: yes, if you substitute in terms of u, everything needs to be expressed in terms of u, du, etc. The $2$ in the first case comes from the fact that $du = (\frac 12(x-2))' = \frac 12 x dx$ so $dx = 2 du.$

Comment: So, in the simple case of $\int \dfrac{1}{x^2+1} dx$, it's $\arctan(x)$ because $1= d(u)$ where $u=x$? How would you give the notation correctly in this case? Also, why is $du$ equal to $1$?

Comment: Then you'd have it evaluating to $\artan x + C$. There wouldn't even be a need to substitute $u = x \implies du = dx$

Comment: @amWhy: Nice way to clarify! +1

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dfrac{x+2}{x^2-4x+8}= \dfrac{x-2}{x^2-4x+8}+4\cdot\frac1{(x-2)^2+2^2}$$

Putting $x^2-4x+8=u,2(x-2)dx=du\implies (x-2)dx=\frac{du}2$

So, $$\int \dfrac{x-2}{x^2-4x+8}=\frac12\cdot\int \frac{du}u=\frac12\cdot\ln|u|+C=\frac12\cdot\ln|x^2-4x+8|+C$$

Putting $x-2=2\tan\theta\implies dx=2\sec^2\theta d\theta$ in $\frac1{(x-2)^2+2^2},$

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x-2)^2+2^2}=\int\frac{2\sec^2\theta d\theta}{4\sec^2\theta}=\frac12\cdot\theta+K=\frac12\cdot\arctan\left(\frac{x-2}2\right)+K$$

Comment: Oops, I was wondering why our results were off: you forgot to carry down /include the factor of $4$ when integrating the second term of the sum at the top. So the second integral should be multiplied by 4.

Comment: @amWhy, I decidedly, left the multiplier apart.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What happens if you calculate $F'(x)$? Where do the $2$'s come from?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't know. The problem cuts both ways

Comment: By now the other answers have all explained this so have a look at those.

Answer (score 0):

$\int$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4} (x-2)^2 +1}$=$4$$\int$$\frac{1}{(x-2)^2+4}$=$\frac{4}{2}$$\int$$\frac{2}{(x-2)^2+4}$=$\frac{4}{2}$$\tan^{-1}\frac{x-2}{2}$=...

You can simplify further. I have used the basics for differentiation of inverse trig functions.